# Secure dynamic images. PHP

Tags: php, security, dynamic, get

I made a php script to create one of several dynamic images to be used as backgrounds for elements on my webpage.
My question is not a coding question and the code works great, so far.

My question is about implementation and possible security issues with using GET to pass data to the bg.php .
Right now the scr of the image looks like this

```
../bg.php?t=1&w=200&h=200
```

Where 
  $t is the type of shape. (array of polygon coordinates)
  $w is the width of the image
  $h is the height of the image

Is using GET safe for this functionality, or is there a better/safer
way of passing the variables to bg.php?

bg.php will be called several times per page and will be used in `<img src="bg.php">` `<style>bg.php</style>` and `<script>bg.php</script>`

Comment: Definitely cache that output

Comment: Will caching the image limit server load?  If an image with the same t, w, and ,h are called again the server will not have to create it?  If so, can I unchache the images.  I also have color and alpha variables that will be stored in cookies since all the elements will be the same color.  Color is user controlled so it will only need to be done if the user changes the color scheme.

Comment: It’s not a question of how the values are passed but what you do with the values. So what do you do with the passed values in you script?

Answer (score 1):

Someone malicious could render an image of any size, assuming you don't check this, someone could use up all memory/storage on your server.

Comment: I will add a check to limit the size of the image.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Is using GET safe for this functionality, or is there a better/safer way of passing the variables to bg.php?

It doesn't matter how user input ends up in your PHP script (`GET`, `POST`, `SERVER`, from a file, from the database, from somewhere else entirely), it's only important what you do with it.

You would need to post your script here if you want us to tell you if it's secure (apart for the DOS possibility mentioned by andy). I could imagine that you do something like `<img src="bg.php?t=[userinput]&w=[userinput]">`, which would for example not be secure.